# MsSql - Optimize Like %value%

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, indexing, full-text-search

Let's consider a simple query `select * from link where value like %test%`. This query has a performance issue since it scans all rows in the table. I need to optimize this query.

I already tried:

- the first idea is using Full-text search, but the is no way to return the same result, which like `'%test%'` returns.
- create a non-clustered index. Works only for `like 'test%'`

I will be grateful for any advice.

Code that explains why Full-text search doesn't work:

```
CREATE  TABLE dbo.Link(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Link NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Link] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] )
)


INSERT INTO dbo.Link VALUES ('https://localhost/smthtest/SendToFriend')
INSERT INTO dbo.Link VALUES ('https://localhost/smthtest/SendToFriend')

 CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON   Link (Link)  KEY INDEX [PK_Link]   ON someYourCatalog

 select * from Link  where link like '%test%'
 select * from Link  where contains(link, 'test')
 select * from Link  where contains(link, '"test"')
 select * from Link  where contains(link, '"test*"')
 select * from Link  where contains(link, '"*test*"')
```

If you run these queries you will see that only the first one returns data.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You can't optimise a `LIKE` clause with a leading wild card. Best you *can* do is start using Full Text Indexes.

Comment: @Larnu See my updates. it shows why Full-Text Indexes doesn't work

Comment: No, it won't work, because `CONTAINS` is looking for specific words (not inside them). But `LIKE` with a leading wild card, like I said, can't be optimised. Seems like you should be storing things like the host name, and share name, etc, as different column entities; and then the full value for the column `link` in your table `link` (that's confusing) should be acomputed column. Then you can index the separate columns.

Comment: @Larnu Even if I split URL to different columns I will still need to search with a leading wild card.

Comment: @BasilKosovan why would you? If the value of the column `ShareName` is `'SmthTest'`. then `WHERE ShareName 'Smth%'` will be index seekable.

Comment: @Larnu Because I don't have value 'Smth'. I have value 'test'.

Comment: Then you have to suffer the poor performance, @BasilKosovan . You are without options.

Comment: It's a reason why I've created this topic. @Larnu

Comment: Only other suggestion I can think of is; don't use SQL Server. Use a data engine that *can* catter for this; which won't be an RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu Which data engine could do that?

Comment: I *suspect* some form of NoSQL; but I have no experience with them, or know if they can do such things (well).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much choice here.

1. You can use a full text index.  I'm not sure why this doesn't work in your case, but it does have its limits.
2. If you are looking for a known set of values, you can use computed columns.  You can index `has_smith as (case when col like '%smth%' then 1 else 0 end) persisted` (normally, you would want more than two values).
3. If you are storing lists of things in a column (such as tags), you can normalize the data.

Beyond this, you get into harder core tricks, such as storing ngrams in a separate indexed table and using that information.  Normally, a full-text index is the way to go.

Comment: see my updates. it shows why Full-Text Indexes doesn't work

Comment: I've already considered the ways that you suggested. But I still need to search with a leading wild card.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the selectivity of the column value, e.g. if lots of rows have the same data in the column value, an index on the column can also help even your query has condition LIKE '%xxx%'. It will use index scan instead of table scan.

But if it is not the case, your options are very limited.

Comment: *"an index on the column can also help even your query has condition LIKE '%xxx%'"* No, it can't. An index can't help when you have a leading wildcard.

Comment: It helps because SQL can leverage the index to have a index scan plan instead of a table scan

Comment: it will not have index seek for sure

Comment: That index isn't going to help, when the OP has a `SELECT *`. *Maybe* it would help if the OP had a statement like `SELECT [value] FROM link WHERE [value] LIKE '%smth%';`, as then the data being scanned is smaller (less wide), but not here. The main benefit of an index is being able to perform that Seek operation you said it won't be able to do. Considering that the OP is returning **every** column, then a table scan is likely to be better than an index scan, followed by a key lookup (and that **assumes** the OP has a Clustered Index).

Comment: SELECT * will cause key lookups. The index will still be used for index scan to get the PKs or rid if it is a heap. Index can + key lookup can have lower cost than table/pk scan depending on selectivity of the column

Comment: Here is an old blog post about this from a MSGTSC member: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varund/2009/11/30/index-usage-by-like-operator-query-tuning/